# ssh localhost gets an error: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh

Need to resolve this issue,
Here's the output using `-v` option:

```
emarguli@DESKTOP-6C25GHF:/$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'emarguli'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:lUNGPHQv3Mh7sr4p6aIz/fW5r8uTRrJrBfHo9nk1gRk
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/emarguli/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/emarguli/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is the multiple `key_load_public: No such file or directory`.  You have no keys generated, while the server is expecting them.

Use `ssh-keygen` to create your keys, then try again.  Simply invoking `ssh-keygen` as the `emarguli` user will create an RSA key for you that should get you going.

For more options, read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen).

After creating the keys, you need to upload the **public** key to the remote server so that it trusts the private key that you have on the client.  Normally, this can be done using the `ssh-copy-id` command:

```
$ ssh-copy-id <user>@<server>
```

but as you're connecting to your local computer, you can simply append the public RSA key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your authorized keys file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Finally, make sure permissions on this last file are correct - it should only be writable by its owner:

```
chown 0640 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: After ssh-keygen execution I can see new files in ~/.ssh dir:

Comment: After ssh-keygen execution I can see new files in ~/.ssh dir:
emarguli@DESKTOP-6C25GHF:/$ ls -al ~/.ssh
total 4
drwx------ 1 emarguli emarguli 4096 Aug  7 14:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 emarguli emarguli 4096 Aug  7 14:25 ..
-rw------- 1 emarguli emarguli 1675 Aug  7 14:17 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 emarguli emarguli  406 Aug  7 14:17 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 emarguli emarguli  222 Aug  5 15:42 known_hosts

But now I'm getting another error:
emarguli@DESKTOP-6C25GHF:/$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
emarguli@DESKTOP-6C25GHF:/$

Comment: I've restarted ssh service and I no longer get "Connection refused".
I still have  the issue with Permission denied (publickey).